# How can I split an image into rectangles?

Tags: image-recognition, aws, ocr

I have a labelled form to which people will add their name and a series of numbers. They will then take a picture of the form. Like so:

[image: rectangles with numbers in them]

I can get decent results by simply sending this to AWS Rekognition

[image: results from Rekognition]

but I feel like it would do even better if I was able to split the image into parts before sending it to the OCR API. What techniques can I use to accomplish this?

I can modify the form for better results if that helps. Maybe make borders more or less dark? Whatever is needed.

Comment: Maybe opencv might help here..

Answer (score 1):

AWS Rekognition works very well for detecting typewritten text but not so well for detecting hand written symbols. You can see this is true in your example. What I would do is detect all the boxes associated with the words `Problem`. Then you can extract a box relative to the position of this word. Then you will have extracted the hand written numbers in each box.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need to do. Thanks! Do you know the names of the algorithms or techniques I could look at in order to learn how to detect the different boxes?